# Java flow control by throwing exceptions

Tags: java, exception, control-flow

I have a question that is bothering me for a while about the preferable flow control method.

I often encounter a situation, where I have to decide what to do based on return value from a method which is `null` or `not null`

So I have two options which I know about, how to deal with it:

Check for null:

```
public class BasedOnNullFlowControl {

    public String process(String login) {
        String redirectUri = getRedirectUri(login);
        if (redirectUri != null) {
            return redirectUri;
        } else {
            return "Your login is taken";
        }
    }

    private String getRedirectUri(String login) {
        Optional<Login> loginFromDb = checkLoginExists(login);
        if (loginFromDb.isPresent()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return "some-redirect-url";
        }
    }

    private Optional<Login> checkLoginExists(String login) {
        return Optional.empty(); //assume this value comes from some API
    }

    private class Login {}
}
```

Or interrupt the flow with exception:

```
public class ExceptionFlowControl {

    public String process(String login) {
        return getRedirectUri(login);
    }

    private String getRedirectUri(String login) {
        Optional<Login> loginFromDb = checkLoginExists(login);

        loginFromDb.ifPresent(l -> {
            throw new LoginExistsException();
        });
        return "some-redirect-url";
    }

    private Optional<Login> checkLoginExists(String login) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private class LoginExistsException extends RuntimeException {
    }

    private class Login {}
}
```

I know, that exceptions should be used only in exceptional situations, but my situation is not exceptional and still second solution looks better for me, because I can add some exception handler (like in Spring) and translate it to some nice Http status code in the end. The controller method `process` is not contaminated with dozens null checks.

Could you smart people please advise which one solution should be used? Or maybe there is a third one?

Comment: Note that if you're using `if(Optional.isPresent())`, then you're just replacing `null` with `Optional`, but not in any sensible way.

Comment: Now look at the mess your question caused.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, now I'm convinced, that there is no single answer to my problem and probably everything depends on who is doing code review :) I just wanted to know if  controlling application flow by exceptions is always a bad practice even if sometimes it looks to be simpler and cleaner that way

Comment: @nibsa Please, consider upvote answer(s) and comment(s) that helps you. Consider as well to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception way allows for less dependency between the parts of the code, so the first way is quite poor. With it you need to pass a `null` value loaded with special meaning (`null == login taken`) all the way from `checkLoginExists()` to `process`.

However It's not the job of `getRedirectUri()` to throw the exception, it should be done in `checkLoginExists()`. I'm a dubious about having `getRedirectUri()` be responsible for checking whether a login exists or not too. Not to mention that using `null` or `Optional` only gives you a binary notion of success/fail. What if the login exists, but is locked, so you have to forbid login as well as creating a new user with the same name. You might want to redirect to a different page to indicate that the login is locked.

Still, this is opinion based, highly dependent on the specifics of the situation and there isn't a clear cut rule that you could follow.

Edit (now that all this hubbub is over with): It is a widely accepted opinion that *normal* flow control should not be done with exceptions. However the definition of *normal* is not so easily defined. You wouldn't write code like

```
int[] array = ...
int i = 0;
try {
    while(true) {
       array[i]++;
       i++;
    }
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Loop finished
}
```

However if you're not using a ridiculously simple example like above, it goes into the gray area.

Note also that exception is not the same as an application error. It is impossible (or at least not sensible) to try to work around exceptions by validating everything. If we consider the presented case where a new user is trying to register a username, and we want to prevent duplicate usernames. You can check for a duplicate and show an error message, but there's still the possibility that two concurrent requests attempt to register the same username. At this point one of them will get an exception, as the database will disallow duplicates (if your system is sensible in anyway).

Validation is important, but there's nothing *truly exceptional* about exceptions. You need to handle them gracefully, so why bother validating if you end up with having to handle an exception anyway. If we take an example case of something I wrote in the comments, where you need to prevent duplicates and curse words as usernames, you might come up with something like this (let's assume this is in `getRedirectUri()`:

```
if(checkForCurseWords(username))
    return "login not allowed";

try {  // We can also omit the try-catch and let the exception bubble upwards
    createLogin(username);
} catch(DuplicateException e) {
    return "login exists";
} catch(Exception e) {
    return "problem with login";
}
return "main page";
```

Comment: I disagree: exceptions should be used only to signal application errors that needs to be fixed, you should avoid exceptions by doing necessery validation before executing logic.

Comment: I completely disagree with that inflexible approach. In this case validation is done, but exceptions are used to indicate validation fail.

Comment: validation fail is... normal logic flow and clearly shouldn't be handled by throwing exception, when you wrote this thousands of little kities have just died.

Comment: How throwing exception that needs to be catched up and served is making less dependency?

Comment: If validation exceptions are a new concept to you, you're trying to answer something that is beyond your capabilities.

Comment: validation exceptions is antipattern, you should know that.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki "validation exceptions is antipattern" - says who? I call BS on that.

Comment: I say that, and anyone who thinks reasonably would say it.

Comment: don't be mislead by your or mine rep points, please think deeply about it: Exceptions should be used only for exceptional (unforseen) situations that are indicating an application error. PLEASE THINK A WHILE ABOUT THIS.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Okay let's forget the points, I've been writing Java for 20 years, how about you? If you have any valid arguments, show them. Saying "PLEASE THINK A WHILE" is worth nothing, coming from you.

Comment: I've been writing software for 24 years, java for 12 years.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I think you're a bit too hung up on "avoid exceptions like the plague". This is not using exceptions to handle normal logic flow. This is a situation where normal logic flow means a new user is created, and exceptions are used to indicate that a new user cannot be created for whatever reason. Going by your suggestion (and my scenario in the answer) we would need a method to check for an existing login, another method to check whether that login is locked, a third method for checking if that login is not allowed (let's say you can't use a curse word for your login) etc. etc.

Comment: The argument is already stated out there: exception=error, other case is just normal logic flow. Using them in other way just donesn't make sense, why then don't you use exceptions for everything? eg insted `if` you could just force the exception to be thrown. There should be clear line between using exceptions and logic, and this is it: exception=error.

Comment: @Kayaman YES, EXACTLY, there should be methods for checking and distinguishing these conditions, instead of throwing some meaningless exception. It is normal logic flow that the login is incorrect, and you should just signal that to user and ask him for valid one.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki "I say that" - sorry,you fail to provide good arguments.

Comment: @lexicore please read carefully, He asked who says that, I answered that i do. Keep your bias controlled.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki There is a method for checking and distinguishing these conditions. It's the `checkLogin()` one. There's no need to pepper dozens of methods around and make huge if-slides for checking separate conditions.

Comment: @Kayaman I pray I could not need to ever maintenace some code wiritten by you.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki You're not taking this discussion to any fruitful direction and seem to be fortified in your position, which I and lexicore deem wrong. How about answering the comments I left on your answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Once again I'm confirmed that exception handling is a religion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use optionals you can avoid the `null` checks altogether:

```
public class BasedOnNullFlowControl {

    public String process(String login) {
        String redirectUri = 
        return getRedirectUri(login).orElse("Your login is taken");
    }

    private Optional<String> getRedirectUri(String login) {
        return checkLoginExists(login).map(ifExists -> "some-redirect-url");
    }

    private Optional<Login> checkLoginExists(String login) {
        return Optional.empty(); //assume this value comes from some API
    }

    private class Login {}
}
```

Next, your second version only looks nice with unchecked exceptions. So this boils down to checked vs. unchecked exceptions. Which is a kind of religious question.

A few years ago I've worked with the software where the previous "generation" of developers followed the unchecked exceptions religion. Like, "we mostly can't handle exceptions reasonably anyway so let's just throw unchecked exceptions and have some routine on the top level to catch them and show the error info dialog to the user". That failed spectacular and it was extremely difficult to refactor it. The code was like a mine field, you could never know what could or could not happen.

After that I've completely switched to the "checked exceptions religion". If you have a situation which would be better described as a programming error (like, passed `null` where no null is expected or access to classpath resource which MUST be there), then a runtime error is suitable. In other cases model and use checked exceptions.

Comment: I disagree: exceptions should be used only to signal application errors that needs to be fixed, you should avoid exceptions by doing necessery validation before executing logic.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki If I write a public method which by contract does not accept `null`s, I'll typically check that with `Objects.requireNonNull`. If someone calls the method with a `null`, they'll get an NPE. In my method, I can't validate "before executing logic", that's nonsense because the logic is already executed.

And no, exceptional situation does not necessarily mean there's an error in the application which should be fixed. It means there's a situation you can't or decide not to handle.

Comment: in such situation, this should be described in the method doc, so the one that invokes your method needs to use it properly (check his values before invoking your method). Or if the checking logic is more complicated, you should give him a method to check like this is done in File class eg `file.exists()`

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Validating input parameters and failing fast on incorrect input is a good practice which helps both sides. Replacing these checks with some Javadoc and hoping that they will be read and considered and that noone would ever make a mistake is very naive.

Answer (score 0):

You will (unfortunately) never get a clear answer for that kind of question because it depends of a lot of factors and lot of those factors are opinion based.

I see nothing completly wrong with your two options. Using exception for the flow control is considered bad practrice in Java (but it is not the case in some other language - like Python) but you got a point when you said

> The controller method process is not contaminated with dozens null
>   checks.

I give you a tricks:
**When you hesitate between two piece of code. Ask yourself which code somebody looking at it for the first time will understand more easily.**

In your second solution, it is clear what happens if the session already exist. In six month another develepper could have a look to your code and very easily find what you are doing in such case by searching for the exception handling.

Given the trick I gave your I found the second option better (in my humble opinion).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have give Him a clear answer. I disagree with you because throwing exception is the worst solution.

Answer (score 0):

Control flow by using exceptions is always **bad idea**, it is broadly explained here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

and here:

http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

The line beewten using exceptions vs normal logic should be clear, so exceptions should be used only for real errors, not for something that can be served by normal application logic.

@lexicore and @Kayaman, you can downvote me now, I do not care.
And... check the second link for the list of **real programmers** who say that you should not use exceptions for normal flow control.
If your ego is irritated because of this, I am really happy.

Answer (score -1):

It depends:

- If the lack of value (or null) is a normal and expected situation in your logic then you should not throw exception, but just serve it accordingly. Consider using a null-object pattern - instead returning null return some object that will represent a "non-value" object, then you can omit the checking for null, since your logic should handle such null object accordingly (often you don't need to write even single line of code in your logic to serve such kind of object).
- if the situation is that you really can't proceed with it you should throw an exception. The exceptions should be used to signal errors in application. If you can avoid exception (eg checking if user specified correct file name using `file.exists()`) beforehand, then you should do that (unless it is really out of the normal logic flow and you just can't proceed).

In your example you really shouldn't throw exception, as it is normal (and expected) situation that user enter incorrect login, this should be handled by normal logic flow.

In your particular situation why don't you just return redirect uri that points to some page with "user don't exist" kind of message?

Comment: So going by your suggestion, whenever we do file IO, we need to check whether the file exists (if reading), whether we have correct permissions, and any other situations before we actually perform IO, instead of handling it through exceptions?

Comment: You've also misread the code in question. It's not about logging in, it's about creating a new user and preventing duplicate logins.

Comment: And even if you check everything before actually doing file IO, it may still fail (ex. file removed between check and IO).

Comment: @Kayaman yes, we should have methods to check if we can perform the desired action. Exceptions should be used only to detect/signal errors in your app.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Is a missing file an "error in your app"?

Comment: @lexicore No, I check if the file exists, if there is problem after that (eg. someone is maliciously deleting my files or the hdd has burned) this is a exception for me.

Comment: So instead of just handling the exception, you want to both validate **and** handle the exception? What kind of advantage does that give you (provided that you're not being paid by LOC)?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki So it is an exception but not application error?

Comment: @Kayaman No, the exception is then considered to be abnormal flow interruption, like unchecked exception and is serverd generally as an unforseen situation that needs closer look and eventualy some fix.

Comment: @lexicore yes, same way OOM is exception, but not neccesserily an application error (but obviously could indicate it eg. memory leak)

Comment: `OOME` is not an exception. It's an `Error`. Don't mix things up.

Comment: @Kayaman when hdd burns out and you get IOException it is also out of your control regardless the subtype you get (it should be `Error`) so things are mixed up already. But it doesn't change anything, it is just some situation that is either indicating error in your app or event that is out of your control

Comment: I'm now going to downvote your answer because of your lack of convincing arguments, your parroting of "Exceptions are evil", and your confusion and misunderstanding of `Error` and `Exception`. I have other business to attend to.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Well, you were saying exception=error all the way and now you're backing off.

Comment: @lexicore How do I back off? exception=error, error is either an application error or really unforseen situation (like hardware malfunction/ resource exhaustion) which obviously always can happen (this don't need explanation)

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Well, now not every exception is an application error, this is how you back off. (Just answering your question.) You have to excuse me, I'll also be leaving the discussion as it is not constructive.

Comment: @lexicore It should be logical for you that generally exception=app error  with the exclusion of hardware malfunction/resource exhaustion, becuse in such case anything can happen, you know that right? The hardware malfunction will render anything to be nonsene, so this is invalid argument form your point. You just catch up this to have you opinion on the top, but it is ridiculous to nagate my approach in such way.